# Translation of "gut x kilometer"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

What's the English translation of "gut dreißig Kilometer"? As in:

> Es befindet sich gut dreißig Kilometer außerhalb von London?

I'm not sure whether it's 'a good thirty kilometres' or 'some thirty kilometres', although I'm tending towards the former.

Comment: Since it is not hard to explain the meaning, you should ask on ELU.

Comment: +1 because it never occurred to me just how handy and concise those two really are: "knapp" and "gut". As for your question: I always thought "some" was the idiomatic equivalent.

Comment: @Em1: Noted, I'll ask the questions that are easy to explain on ELU. Perhaps that's why your questions usually get closed there, wrong theory.

Comment: Besides the answers another alternative might be "just a little more than 30 km"

Comment: A discussion with Matt Эллен (on ELU) pointed out that "a good" is an idiomatic casual phrasing. He's not entirely sure if it always mean "greater". Alternatives are "just over", "barely over", "nearly over", ... Normally you have to add "over" or "under" to determine the direction, but "odd" will mean a bit more, while "nearly" and "close to" might've the meaning of less than.

Comment: So, first I [asked on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/73444/16833) and then Matt [goes more into detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/73457/16833). Both will answer you're question completely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From a discussion on [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=647054&idForum=1&lp=ende&lang=de):

> Just over thirty kilometers.

When combined with something countable, *gut* means *slightly more* (it's opposite being *knapp*, which means slightly less).

Comment: So, as opposite you can take "just under" :)

Comment: Interesting. I always used "gut" in the sense of "about" or "circa" but [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gut#Bedeutung3b) confirms your statement that it always means "a bit more".

Comment: @musiKk: If you want to say "about" you use "rund" or "etwa".

Comment: @celtschk: Yeah, I know. It's just something that I apparently mistook my whole life.

Answer (score 3):

A literal English translation of "gut dreißig Kilometer" is "a good thirty kilometers."

In this case, the literal English translation is also a accurate translation of the German. They both mean "30 kilometers" PLUS.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would say

> about thirty kilometres

Comment: I think this would be the one to choose for `ungefähr dreißig Kilometer` ... `around thirty kilometres` would also fit for that one.

Comment: This really doesn't fit "_gut_ dreißig Kilometer"!